# Add extra 'show' page with PDF [Laravel9]

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm studying web.php about Adding one extra show page.
I use one of sample CRUD program.

I'm trying to make show page with PDF print.
PDF generate function is fine. I can download the pdf file.but I can't the single record.
currently I wrote like this.

web.php

```
//I can download pdf file but I can't get single one record.
Route::get('/generate_pdf', [StudentController::class, 'generate_pdf'])->name('generate_pdf');


// below code works fine
     Route::resource('ddd',  StudentController::class)->parameters([
            'ddd' => 'student'
        ]);
```

Controller

```
public function generate_pdf(Student $student, $id)
   {
    $data = Student::whereId($student->id)->first();
    $date = new Carbon();        
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', compact('data'));     

    return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
}

   public function show(Student $student)
    {
        return view('show', compact('student'));
    }
```

mypage.blade.php(When User click this link, PDF download starts.)

```
    <a href="{{ route('generate_pdf',
   $row->id)}}"class="btn btn-primarybtn-sm">
   print PDF</a>
```

pdf.blade.php

I wrote like this same as show.blade.php

```
   <h1>PDF PRINT </h1>

   Name :    {{ $student->student_name }}

   Email:    {{ $student->student_email }}
```

Could you correct my code please?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. I also think you don't understand what a resource route is. You should probably give [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers) a good read.

Comment: Dear @miken32 Thank you for answering me and I'm sorry about my explanation. I add more info. 
what I would like to do is When user click link One record show up with PDF.
PDF function works fine. but somehow I can't not get selected one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I would like to do is When user click link One record show up with PDF. PDF function works fine. but somehow I can't not get selected one record.

You would need to have the student reference passed in the route.

```
Route::get('generate_pdf/{student}', [
    StudentController::class,
    'generate_pdf'
])->name('generate_pdf');
```

There is no need of the second parameter in the controller function

```
public function generate_pdf(Student $student)
{
    $date = new Carbon(); // remove this if not used

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', compact('student'));     

    return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
}
```

Also update the link in the blade file to:

```
<a href="{{ route('generate_pdf', ['student' => $row->id]) }}"
   class="btn btn-primarybtn-sm"
>Print PDF</a>
```

References:

- [Route Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-route)
- [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: Dear @linktoahref Thank you very much.
This is perfect! I really learned a lot of your answer code. Thank you!